# algorithms: Implementing custom hash table based dict

Tags: actionscript-3, algorithm, cryptography

I am learning programming abstract data types. Trying to build custom hash table based dict.

SO far I've created a class place holder.

```
    public class HashMapDict implements IDict
{
    private var _map:Array;
    public function HashMapDict()
    {
        _map = new Array();

        //TODO: implement function
    }

    public function set(keys:Array):Boolean
    {
        // 1. For each key in array of keys
        // 2. Pass Key.key to hash function
        // 3. Write Key to _map[hash(Key.key)]
        return true;
    }


}
```

I see the main method set doing the following

```
// 1. For each key in array of keys
// 2. Pass Key.key to hash function
// 3. Write Key to _map[hash(Key.key)]
```

What I am thinking about is to use cryptography libs for hash generation. But I am a bit confused with how it should work. e.g. Tried to look on several libs like as3crypto (http://crypto.hurlant.com/demo/) and it seems to produce hash in a way I don't really think can be used for indexes in arrays.

E.g.

http://screencast.com/t/bE1lYQEqp4D

Can you advise which lib can I use to generate usable hashes? and how should they look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For implementation of a hash table, a cryptographic hash function is overkill.

Use this only if you are concerned with an attack of someone who tries to feed you bad data (e.g. keys with lots of hash collisions) to make the hash table slow.

For a hash table use, a hash function like the following one is enough (pseudocode, as I don't know the right syntax):

```
hash = 0
for c in string:
   hash = hash * 13 + c;
return hash
```

But as other answers said, there is already a hash table built in, and you don't really need to reimplement it.

Comment: I am doing it just for education purposes. In real application I will use already implemented dictionaries. what is the idea of your code?

Comment: My hash code (which is a pretty standard one, I think, except maybe for the selection of 13) is a polynomial with the character codes as coefficients, evaluated at 13. (Use any other number there - but prime numbers do best.) [Java's String.hashCode() does something similar, with 31 instead of 13.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#hashCode())

Comment: Tried this approach. In general for key = "bob" it generated a hash code = 337. So by inserting an item with such key in the array e.g. _map[337] = MYKEY i will get an array of 337 empty elements (and one not empty). do you think it's ok? I am just a bit worried if it's fine to create such a big arrays in the memory

Comment: No, you wouldn't use such a big array. Instead, pick some size `N` (depending on the number of entries in your table - for example, 16 for up to 10 elements), and then use `hash % N` as index into your array. (`%` is the modulo function here.) You'll need a strategy to handle hash collisions, too. Have a look at the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for details.

Comment: but in the case the Dict will not be auto expanding, yes? Also i think i can quite easily face cases with collisions... Do you know what standard dicts are dong to prevent such cases?

Comment: I don't know anything about JavaScript's Dict, but Java's hash-based collections (Hashtable, HashMap, ConcurrentHashMap, IdentityHashMap, WeakHashMap) allocate a new array (i.e. increase `N`, for example `N = 2*N`) and redistribute the objects by their hash code, when there are "too many" entries in the table. (Yes, this rehashing is a bit expensive (O(number of entries)), thus if you know how many entries there will be, make `N` big enough for those in the beginning.)

Answer (score 2):

Just as a heads up -- I can almost guarantee that you will not be able to make something better than `Dictionary` or even `Object` at this. Your proposed plan could work, but it would offer no benefit over these. I also feel compelled to suggest Vector over Array as Vectors are faster and more powerful.

The problem with Hash libs is that they generally result in very, very large numbers. MD5, for example, will produce a hex string which represents far more than what can fit even into a uint (uint in as can fit 2 ^ 32, MD5 is 2^128). This also happens to be the [maximum size of an Array/Vector in AS.](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee5.html)

This isn't to say that they can't fit into `Number` (which can hold about 1.79*10^308), but it does mean that you'll lose the benefit of numeric indexing and you certainly won't get much benefit from Vectors at that point. You'll basically be falling back on `Object`.

To be honest, it really does look like you have one of two options. Either you can implement a direct lookup using a second Array/Vector. This has the problem of being O(n) lookup time while the lookup time of a Hash table would be O(1).

It seems, at least to me, that you'll need to use `Dictionary` or `Object` no matter what to get this done.

Answer (score 0):

I might be missing something, but I think you should look at `flash.utils::Dictionary`.
It makes hashing obsolete. If you *must* have some sort of primitive key, I suggest using the following:

```
class UIDUtil {
    static private var map:Dictionary = new Dictionary(true);
    static private var counter:int = 0;
    static public function getUID(value:*):int {
         return map[value] ||= counter++;
    }
}
```

But your class I would implement as:

```
public class HashMapDict implements IDict {
    private var _map:Dictionary = new Dictionary();
    public function set(keys:Array):Boolean {
        for each (var key:* in keys) _map[key] = key;
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am not sure of its purpose though ;)

Comment: what is  return map[value] ||= counter++;

Comment: That is a fancy syntax for lazy instantiation. What it does: if map[value] == null, then it is filled with counter (which increases every time)